# 404 - Page not found when accessing repos with Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I was able to log into my Organization's Azure Dashboard and the only thing that is missing on the left side bar is the repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the project administrator?  It is possible that Repos are disabled for that project for all users.  You can find this under the project settings, Overview tab.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Matt thank you for your response.  I am not the administrator.  I can ask the owner/administrator to check if that is the case.

Comment: I would recommend you check with that person then on either the project configuration for it or possibly missing security on any repositories.

Answer (score 9):

If it's not a disabled "Repos" in Options as Matt wrote, ask your administrator to check your Access Level in Organization Settings.

[image]

We had similar issue recently, and it turned out, user had "Visual Studio Subscriber" assigned in settings, but no subscription assigned to Microsoft Account. Changing to Basic solves the problem.